# aggregate queries and sum of results

Tags: django, django-models

my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
  a =  models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  b =  models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  c =  models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  d =  models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to calculate `SUM` over each field and also include into the query set an expression using the results of the aggregation:

```
MyModel.objects.aggregate(a_s=Sum('a'),
                          b_s=Sum('b'),
                          c_s=Sum('c'),
                          d_s=Sum('d')).extra(select={'diff': 'a_s+b_s-c_s-d_s'})
```

I am getting this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'extra'
```

how is this supposed to be done using the ORM?

Comment: aggregate returns a dictionary. can you not process the diff after you get the queryset ?

Comment: I can of course process the queryset after I get it, I was just trying to do it in one statement. I tried using `annotate` instead of `aggregate`, which returns a queryset, but still cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all().extra(select={'diff': 'SUM(a + b) - SUM(c + d)'})
for obj in qs:
    print obj.diff
```

**Edit**

```
result_dict = MyModel.objects.extra(
    select={
        'diff': 'SUM(a) + SUM(b) - SUM(c) - SUM(d)',
        'a_s': 'SUM(a)',
        'b_s': 'SUM(b)',
        'c_s': 'SUM(c)',
        'd_s': 'SUM(d)'
    }).values('diff', 'a_s', 'b_s', 'c_s', 'd_s')
```

This will return a `dict` which will have result of the expression `a + b - c - d` and sum of individual fields.

Comment: @akonsu But this will give overall `diff`. Maybe you want to group by something?

Comment: thanks. I do not need to group, I need overall `SUM`, but I need sum of each field separately, and a sum of the expression `a + b - c - d` in the same queryset.

Comment: @akonsu see my updated answer and let me know if that what you want